# How would i store a number/string into R.string.xx?

Tags: android, string, settext

with this code, my program just force close(error)

```
***public View x = findViewById(R.string.nfoname);***
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
setContentView(R.layout.information);
//edittext
***final EditText infoname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.infoname);***

//clear,confirm
Button clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonclear);
Button confirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonconfirm);

//clear button
clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        infoname.setText("");
    }
});
//confirm button
confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ***x=(View) infoname.getText();***
    }
});
}
```

the one with the *** are the source of error

program function:
if the user clicks confirm, his name will be set to R.string.nfoname
which will then be used in another layout through TextView x = setText(R.string.nfoname);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that you can save text to the R.string.   This is a generated class that the compiler creates for you.  It gets packaged with your apk.  Think of the resources as a means of translation and to present text to the screen.

I think what you would want to do is save the user input as a SharedPreference or in a database.

See:[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) on the android docs for an example usage.

Comment: thanks,

i have used this..

TextView x = (TextView) findViewById(<some id>);
x.setText("hello " + getString(R.string.nfoname));

it worked great but how about setting something into string?

an abstract in my mind is something like

idontknow x = (idontknow) findViewById(R.string.stringname);

so that whenever i change x the R.string.stringname would also change

Answer (score 0):

At least in the case of your variable infoname scoping is most likely causing your application to throw an error.  infoname is a local variable to the function onCreate(), not an instance variable for your class, so it can't be accessed by your onClick() methods because they are part of an anonymous class.

Another thing I'd question is why you marked infoname as final? It goes out of scope when onCreate() exits so if it gets changed, you can see who changed it since it only exists while the method is executing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set values to R.string.xxx because all these values will be constants much like a read only stuff. If you want to use the value of edit text to another layout use class variables or `intent.putextra()`

Coming to ur source code i see this

```
public View x = findViewById(R.string.nfoname);
```

How can a view be found by R.String? This should be R.id.

final EditText infoname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.infoname);
Why this editText has to be final?

```
***x=(View) infoname.getText();***
```

You just use `infoname.getText().toString()` you will get the string value of the Edittext's current text. 
Dude you can do stuff simply.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View x = findViewById(R.string.nfoname);
```

This can't work as not only are you trying to find a `View` using a `R.string` resource id, you are doing it before `setContenView(...)` is called in your `onCreate(...)` method. Even if you used a valid `View` resource id such as `R.id.infoname` then `x` will be `null` because the content view hasn't been inflated yet.

```
final EditText infoname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.infoname);
```

Apart from the pointless use of `final` this should'nt cause problems as long as `R.id.infoname` is actually the resource id of an `EditText`.

```
x=(View) infoname.getText();
```

Not only will `x` be `null` but calling `getText()` on an `EditText` returns an `Editable` which is not a `View` nor is it possible to cast it to `View`. Even if you used `getText().toString()` which is the correct way to get the text from an `EditText` it still wouldn't be possible to cast a `String` to a `View`.

Also, as for this...

> TextView x = setText(R.string.nfoname);

It would have to be...

```
TextView x = (TextView) findViewById(<some id>);
x.setText(getString(R.string.nfoname));
```