# do i need global variable or R.string.x is ok?

Tags: android, string, variables, global

an abstract in my mind is something like

idontknow x = (idontknow) findViewById(R.string.stringname);

so that whenever i change x the R.string.stringname would also change

and thus i can use the R.string.stringname anywhere in the same project

but obviously it is an error

edit: 
i would like to input my name(R.string.name or global) and age(R.string.age or global) on an EditText field on a formActivity

and in another differentActivity i would like  to have this:

```
TextView x = (TextView) findViewById(<some id>);
x.setText("Hello "+ getString(R.string.nfoname)+ "you are"+getString(R.string.nfoname)+"years old");
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Could you please clarify? Also, formatting your question properly and using correct grammar/capitalisation might make people more inclined to answer.

Comment: I think you should read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888672/983430) to another question you asked a short time ago. You seem to be misunderstanding the purpose of `R.string.x` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really seems like poor design.  What are you doing that you don't know the type of x, and it's something that you need to persist across your application?

Everything that gets returned by findViewById() is a View object or one of its subclasses.  So, right off the bat you know you have a view object.  Another thing is that findViewById doesn't accept a String as a parameter, it only accept an int value, such that R.id.myVar is actually an integer corresponding to a View in the inflated hierarchy.

If you absolutely have to do something like that, why wouldn't you just use a common id value so that you're always searching for the same id and assign it to a generic View object that can be compared using instanceof later? Like this:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.generic_id);
if(view instanceof TextView) {TextView actualView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.generic_id);}
else {ImageView actualView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.generic_id);}
return actualView;
```

In that case, your ID could be a constant that couldn't be changed, and you always can figure out what subclass of View you're dealing with.  This feels like a more maintainable design than having global variables floating around, in my opinion

Comment: uhm, what does "if(view instanceof TextView) " means? thanks -beginner :(

Comment: It lets you determine what exact subclass you are dealing with.  findViewById will always return something that inherits from the View baseclass, but instanceof gives you a way to determine exactly which subclass you're dealing with (ImageView, TextView, LinearLayout, etc) by comparing the object that you got back from findViewById to the class signature of the each of those View types.

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.<anything>` are ids of strings defined in your string.xml file.  The line

```
idontknow x = (idontknow) findViewById(R.string.stringname);
```

will fail because the parameter to `findViewById` is an id, which you can find in `R.id.<anthing>`.

If you are saying you want to define the name and age in the string.xml file, then you do have access from any `Activity` or `View` in your code.

What I suspect you actually want is to have a name and age variable that is settable and accessible from multiple views.  To pass data from one `Activity` to another `Activity`, you can put them into the extras in the `Intent`.

For example, in Activity1.java where you start Activity2.java, you could do something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("Name", name); // name is a variable with the name value you want to send
i.putExtra("Age", age); // age is a variable with the age value you want to send
startActivity(i);
```

Then, in Activity2.java, you can get the extras you put into the Intent, something like:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
name = extras.getString("Name");
age = extras.getInt("Age");
```